# Exceptions to Brown's Criterion

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation

Recently, I've been playing a lot with [Brown's Criterion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrownsCriterion.html) and writing numbers as a sum of members of a sequence. However, I have observed that Brown's Criterion does not seem to be entirely accurate for some sequences.

For example, take the Tribonacci sequence ($x_n = x_{n-1} + x_{n-w} + x_{n-3}$) and apply it for initial conditions $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 1, x_3 = 1$. The first few terms are listed below:

$$
1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 31, 57
$$

Because this is a Tribonacci sequence, the ratio between terms as the number of members approaches infinity is approximately 1.839, which is less than 2. For all terms *except* one, Brown's Criterion is met. The term which does not follow Brown's Criterion is the fourth term, 3, as it is is greater than two times the previous term. Yet I can *still* express every positive integer as a sum of members of this sequence.

Am I wrong? And, if not, are there other exceptions to Brown's Criterion?

Comment: The criterion is "if" i.e. it guarantees completeness, but not "only if" - it is not necessary for completeness. If I begin with a long sequence of $1$s I can continue $3,9,27 \dots$, for example, and complete by adding at each stage the first integer not yet represented. Say $39=3+9+27$ ones to be sure. I can also do something like $1,1,1,3,7,13,27 \dots$ where I introduce a little redundancy to get alternating rations greater than $2$

Comment: @MarkBennet The material I had seen stated that it was an "iff" relationship for completeness. :\ Guess that's a source problem. EDIT: Actually, _all_ of the sources I have seen state that it's an "iff" relationship. Is there a better source for this subject?

Comment: From what I see in the references, the condition $x_{n+1}\le2\,x_n$ is a sufficient but not necessary condition for completeness of he sequence $\{x_n\}$. It is a corollary of Brown´s criterion, $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x_k\le x_n-1$.